# Form submission using backbone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, backbone.js

I am using **Backbone** to submit a form. The form resides in html page (home page). I used **.save()** method of backbone model to save data in database when the form submitted. I used **e.preventDefault();** to prevent submission and catch the values.

The problem is after submission the form remain unchanged that means input fields filled up with previous values.If I again submit the form then previous values insert in database.

How is it possible to make the form as like first state(blank) after submission ??

**Codes**

**HTML**

```
<form  method="post" id="my_form">                    
     <input type="text" id="name" size="30"  required autofocus/>
     <input type="email" id="email " size="30" required/>
     <input type=" text " id="catagory" size="30" required/>                        
     <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**backbone**

```
var My_view = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    el: $("body"),
    events: 
    {
        "submit #my_form": "save"    
    }, 
    initialize: function()
    {
        _.bindAll(this,'save');
    },
    save: function(e)
    {  
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();  
        var catagory = $('#catagory').val(); 

        var data = {
            name : name, 
            email : email, 
            catagory : catagory 
        };

        var my_model = new My_model();              

        my_model.save(data, 
        {
            success: function(model,response) 
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function(model,response)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));     
            }
        }); 
    }
});


var my_view = new My_view({});
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: are you just going to keep displaying the same form after submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is clear the form, then in your `success` callback to the `save` method just add some javascript to do it like this:

```
my_model.save(data, 
        {
            success: function(model,response) 
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                $('#myForm')[0].reset(); //native javascript
            },
            error: function(model,response)
            {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));     
            }
});
```

Bear in mind that this will be confusing for your user - if they press submit and then the form just seems to delete their responses. You'd be better off hiding the form: `$('#myForm').hide()` then displaying a message saying that the form was submitted successfully. Or redirecting them to a submission success page.